# Formatar float no Python

Tags: python-3.x

Como devo fazer para mostrar apenas duas casas decimais usando o "float" no Python
print('O peso médio dessas pessoas é: {}'.format(media))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
print('O peso médio dessas pessoas é: {:.{prec}f}'.format(media, prec=2))
```

ou, simplificando:

```
print('O peso médio dessas pessoas é: {:.2f}'.format(media))
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia usar o operador de formatação de string para isso:

```
    '%.2f' % 1.234
    '1.23'
    '%.2f' % 5.0
    '5.00'
```

O resultado do operador é uma string, então você pode armazená-lo em uma variável, imprimir etc.

No caso do uso de Python 3.6 segue a sintaxe - a string é colocada entre aspas, como de costume, com prefixo f'... da mesma maneira que você faria r'... para uma string bruta. Então você coloca qualquer coisa que queira colocar dentro de sua string, variáveis, números, dentro de chaves

```
    print('O peso médio dessas pessoas é: {a:.2f}'.format(media))
```

Se você realmente quiser alterar o número em si, em vez de exibi-lo de forma diferente, use format ()

Formate-o para 2 casas decimais:

```
    format(5.00000, '.2f')
    '5.00'
```